# authentication failed: generic failure in digitalocean mail server

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail, digital-ocean

I am trying to send email but it is not sending out. Each time i am getting error "authentication failed: generic failure".

Below is my code. I don't know what i am missing here.

```
    @Test
public void test() {
    BaseMail mail = MailFactory.getMail();
    mail.setFrom("myfrom@mail.domainname.com");
    mail.setTo("to@domainname.com");
    mail.setPersonal("Test");
    mail.setSubject("Test Email");
    mail.setContent("Test Email");          
    try {
        Transport.send(getMessage(mail));
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}

public static Session getSession(){
    if(session == null){
        Properties props = new Properties();
        TKAuthenticator auth = null;
        try {
            props.put("mail.smtp.host","mail.mydomain.com");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port","587");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
            props.put("mail.debug","true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.from","bounce@mail.mydomain.com");
            auth = new TKAuthenticator("username@mail.mydomain.com", "password");

        session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
        session.setDebug(true);         

    }
    return session;
}
```

This is my log:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1ea-SNAPSHOT
DEBUG: getProvider() returning         javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun     Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mail.mydomain.com", port 587, isSSL     false
220 mail.mydomain.com ESMTP Postfix
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "mail.mydomain.com", port: 587
250-mail.mydomain.com
250 DSN
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "10240000"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
AUTH LOGIN
334 FADSF
Z3N1c2VyQFADSFADFAG1haWZnNtYXNoLmNvbQ==
334 QFVDASVCV
FADSIFOIA FOIADI FAF==
535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: generic failure
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
```

Please try to have a look.

Comment: You're using a very old version of JavaMail, [please upgrade](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/).  Of course the obvious answer to your question is that you've supplied the wrong user name or password.  If you don't think that's the case, you'll need to look at the server logs or get help from your server vendor.

Comment: @BillShannon Server side: I am able to send test message using command. https://github.com/HVboom/HowTo-DigitalOcean/wiki/Postfix and checked username and password is correct.

Comment: @BillShannon server log: **Feb 20 04:13:55 mail postfix/smtpd[29126]: Feb 20 04:13:55 mail postfix/smtpd[29126]: 
warning: hostname walkerj2352.example.com does not resolve to address 91.200.12.92: Name or service not known
Feb 20 04:13:55 mail postfix/smtpd[29126]: connect from unknown[91.200.12.92]
Feb 20 04:13:55 mail postfix/smtpd[29126]: warning: SASL authentication failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: Connection refused
Feb 20 04:13:55 mail postfix/smtpd[29126]: warning: unknown[91.200.12.92]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: generic failure
**

Comment: The test message you pointed to above is sending mail locally without using SMTP or authentication so it's not comparable to what you're doing with JavaMail.  From the server log it's clear that the saslauthd authentication server is not running.  Start by fixing that.